# restart server using shell script in jenkins

Tags: shell, jenkins, server

We are using jenkins to restart our servers. The order of execution is as follows:

1. Stop server1
2. Stop server2
3. Start server2
4. Start server1

I have created a jenkins 'Free style project', where server1 and server2 stops as expected and server2 starts as expected.
But console gets hanged after server2 has started, which does not initiate to start server1.
There is no space related issues in our jenkins application.
Can anyone let me know how to resolve this issue..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, to get a proper answer would you please provide some code to see how are you getting this problem? Thanks

Comment: You are running the current script in Server 1 or Server 2??? How are you making sure that Server 2/1 is up in the script?? then do you have any script that's gonna run with 2/1 to invoke other server1/2 at starting time of the server????

Comment: I am running my script through jenkins. It is a shell script, where i am connecting to my server through 'ssh' command. Eg: ssh user@server name path_where_shellscript_(to start server is kept) StartAll;                          Then command is a parameterised.